# Inverse of sigmoid equation

Tags: functions

I hope someone can help me.

I have this green function **f** (a sigmoid), and I would like to have the equation of the blue function that is the "mirror" of **f** by the red function.

I have no idea how to achieve that.

Can someone help me please ?

[image]

Comment: Apart from the shift by 0.5 in y-direction, you are looking for the inverse function of $f$. A simple calculation gives $g(x) = \frac 1a \cdot \ln \left( \frac{1+2x}{1-2x} \right) + \frac 12$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qaoklvaby7.

Comment: Hey. I didn't know that $ \log(x) \cdot \ln(10) = \ln(x) $ . It's great, thank you.

Comment: Inverse of sigmoid is logit and you can see here the step by step https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3480014/logit-to-sigmoid-explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks similar to $\arccos(-x)$ but for the sigmoid funtion its inverse is denoted as [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) fuction maybe with some scaling and translations easy to apply.

Comment: Hey, it's pretty close, thank you : http://prntscr.com/q11i1f

Comment: @Filimindji Ah you have used $\arccos (-x)$. And what about logit function?

Comment: I'm looking how to use the logit, I cant yet figure how to use the alpha parameter from the sigmoid : log( x*alpha / (1 - x*alpha)) do not give the result I expected.

Comment: Not sure how I came to this approximation, but this work well : http://prntscr.com/q11rhl (sorry about that, I'm pretty sure it's horible to put random value in the equation to just make it look like what I want)

Comment: Yes it looks fine!

Comment: Looks like it's better to use ln(10) instead of the approximation 2.3 I used. So far : http://prntscr.com/q1239d. I'm not really happy with the m - x at the end of the equation, but still, it fit my needs