# Logit to sigmoid explanation?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, machine-learning

How do you achieve the sigmoid function step by step?
I’ve read it’s the opposite of the logit function, so logit could be a starting point. Even to I don’t understand why we do the log to the odds formula either.

1 How do we achieve:

log(p/(1−p))    Inverse->  1/(1+e^(-x))

2 And:

Why do we do the log of p/(1−p) And how can i intuitively see the why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: solution]

Somebody also told me this solution which I find easier

Answer (score 2):

Set $x=\log\frac{p}{1-p}$. Then
\begin{align*}
x&=-\log \frac{1-p}{p}\\
-x&=\log\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)\\
e^{-x}&=\frac{1}{p}-1\\
e^{-x}+1&=\frac{1}{p}\\
p&=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}.
\end{align*}
The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) on the logit function provides a nice history of the function and applications where it is used.

Comment: Thank you, I searched for this everywhere! Also, might be silly but any idea why we do the log to the odds function?

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article?